Ghostwriter snap requires pandoc but doesn't find it, how to resolve?
On my Ubuntu MATE 24.04 setup, I have recently started using Ghostwriter to write documentation, take notes in Markdown format, with the hope that I'd later convert them to HTML or PDF using pandoc. In fact, I realized that Ghostwriter itself uses pandoc for rendering the Markdown in most of the "Markdown render themes" (beyond the plain, and rather basic built-in renderer). Since this is a snap, installing pandoc on host doesn't seem to help. Any guidance on how can I resolve this ? Should I consider installing Ghostwriter directly, i.e. not as a snap ? The main benefit of installing snap was to keep the KDE dependency baggage limited to the snap sandbox.

Check out Marker, which is similar to ghostwriter, but is GTK based https://github.com/fabiocolacio/Marker

Install ghostwriter as a traditional package instead.
sudo snap remove ghostwriter
sudo apt install ghostwriter

If you want to minimize the unnecessary KDE dependencies, use,
sudo apt install ghostwriter --no-install-recommends

If you want to integrate the ghostwriter snap with pandoc, you will have to write to the snap packager of ghostwriter so that they package pandoc with it.

If you want to avoid KDE dependencies, use Marker, a GTK based app similar to ghostwriter.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/marker
sudo apt update
sudo apt install marker


Another non-KDE alternative is Joplin, which supports syncing your notes for free with dropbox and onedrive.
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurent22/joplin/dev/Joplin_install_and_update.sh | bash


@SUTerliakov Thanks for pointing the typo

Marker seems to be quite promising. I couldn't configure the font sizes used in editor though, and if you use CTRL-mousewheel to resize preview window, you lose side-by-side sync between markdown and it's render. Is there a discussion forum, or mailing list for this tool ?

@bdutta74 You can report bugs at https://github.com/fabiocolacio/Marker/issues. However, it seems that the developer is busy and may take a while to respond

@bdutta74 Also check out Joplin. It supports taking notes with markdown and exporting them (and lot more). Moreover, you can sync your notes for free with dropbox or onedrive https://joplinapp.org/
